# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions

Tags: nltk

```
training = []
bos_cikti = [0] * len(siniflar)

for belge in belgeler:
    bag = []
    kelime_patternleri = belge[0]
    kelime_patternleri = [ayristirici.lemmatize(kelime.lower()) for kelime in kelime_patternleri]
    for kelime in kelimeler:
        bag.append(1) if kelime in kelime_patternleri else bag.append(0)

    cikti_sira = list(bos_cikti)
    cikti_sira[siniflar.index(belge[1])] = 1
    training.append([bag, cikti_sira])

random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training)   ------> This line Wrong
```

It shows the error on this line

```
train_x = list(training[:, 0])
train_y = list(training[:, 1])


#Neural Network (YSA)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation="softmax"))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=sgd, metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
model.save("chatbot_model.model")
print("Done")
```

Super confused. When I run my code, I keep on getting this error:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 1 dimensions. The detected shape was (2,) + inhomogeneous part.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Elvan Ersöz\Desktop\Python\Bitirme Projesi\training.py", line 55, in <module>
    training = np.array(training)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (20, 2) + inhomogeneous part.
```

I am creating a project using neural networks and natural language processing. While I'm writing my model
from line 55 I get the following error: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (20, 2) + inhomogeneous part.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPBnA.png)

Comment: Could you solve it? I have the same issue.